# the meaning of "Girl you're every woman in the world to me."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Girl you're **every woman in the world** to me.

This sentence is a part of lyrics of a song 'Every Woman In The World' by Air Supply.

(You can find full lyrics [here](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/a/air+supply/every+woman+in+the+world_20004809.html).)

I roughly know the meaning of the sentence, "I LOVE YOU",

but I want to know about its meaning more specifically. Does it mean

- you are the only woman in the world that I care about:

or does it mean literally:

- you have so many attractive attributes and characters thereby I experience every woman through you?

Comment: Please provide the name of the song (I'm not sure if you have), a link to the song lyrics, and a link to a video of the song being performed. That's the minimum I would expect a question like this to contain. One sentence is rarely acceptable for a question of any sort. In the end, it *may* be that there is no canonical or "right" interpretation of the phrase because lyrics are like poetry and wide open to interpretation.

Comment: @GoDucks I already provided the name of the song. Maybe you missed it. I followed your advice and attached a link to the song lyrics.

Comment: I think the meaning is already in the song, in the lines nearby, the chorus part.

Comment: It cannot mean that the singer wants to "experience every woman through you" (and even if he did he's not going to be telling this one woman that!) because the one woman is everything to him. So it's more like I don't need any other woman because, metaphorically, you are every woman in the world to me. Just like you are everything I need. He doesn't need any other woman; this woman *is* every other woman. It's a metaphor.

Comment: I normally frown on lyric interpretation questions, but I can see how this would be a very tricky idiom for a learner. As a native speaker, I find the phrase intuitive to understand yet hard to explain; I think @GoDucks did a pretty good job of interpreting the metaphor.

Comment: @GoDucks, you should make it an answer. Don't leave it like that.

Comment: Sometimes lyrics just don't make sense as a standalone sentence

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion comes nowhere near the realisation contained in the verse line. And,  your alternative suggestion, (by prevaricating Dr. Johnson's remark about Samson Agonistis) has a good beginning but no grand ending. It failed to keep up the tone and mood.

What the lyricist wants to mean is that you are the embodiment of womanhood. Throuh you, I realise what it means to be a woman. In you, womanhood finds its consummation and fulfillment (mind and matter put together!). You are the representative figure of an ideal woman — Girl you're every woman in the world to me.